# Dynamically update JTextArea in GUI

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jtextarea, swingworker

I'm trying to dynamically update a JTextArea, the code I currently have is below:

```
Object buttonPressed = e.getSource();
if (buttonPressed.equals(uploadSend)){
 new Thread(){

   @Override public void run(){
  Upload send = new Upload();
  send.sendupload();
   for (String rec : uploadList.getUploadDetails()) {                 
       uploadDetails.append(rec.toString());
       uploadDetails.append("\n");
   }
}     
 }.start();
}
```

This works by sending theeupload when the JButton is pressed and the JButton no longer freezes, but the text in the JTextArea is still not displaying until the whole upload task is complete.

I've read up about SwingWorker, is this what i'm missing and how would I implement this here?

Comment: Most of gui methods are not thread safe, so changing gui in another thread rather than the EDT is not going to work

Comment: `"I've read up about SwingWorker, is this what i'm missing..."` -- it could help you with your Swing Background threading, yes. `"... and how would I implement this here?"` -- No idea based on what you've posted. If it were my project, I'd read [the SwingWorker tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and then try to use it. Then if that doesn't work, post my attempt here. 1+ to MadProgrammer's answer which if you follow **his ideas**, will help you to create **your own correct code**. Note that you should never try to just copy and paste code blindly.

Answer (score 4):

It's difficult to know why your text area isn't been updated, as you've not provided enough context to diagnose the problem, consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

But, if you wanted to convert the current logic to use a `SwingWorker`, you could use something like...

```
public class UploadWorker extends SwingWorker<List<String>, String> {

    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground() throws Exception {
        Upload send = new Upload();
        send.sendupload();
        for (String rec : uploadList.getUploadDetails()) {
            publish(rec);
        }
        return uploadList.getUploadDetails();
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
        for (String text : chunks) {
            uploadDetails.append(rec);
            uploadDetails.append("\n");
        }
    }

}
```

Then you would simply call it using something like...

```
if (buttonPressed.equals(uploadSend)){
    UploadWorker worker = new UploadWorker();
    worker.execute();
}
```

Take a look at [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details

Comment: Thanks but I can't get your code to run.  I don't know what other part of my code would help describe the problem?

Comment: It's not about "what other part of the code would help", it's about provide a [**runnable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which **demonstrates** your problem.  It just needs to be small compilable and runnable example which is focused on replicating the problem you are having

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I pasted back the results of `uploadList.getUploadDetails()` which (I assume) is either a `List<String>` or `String[]`, but I don't have any code to prove it one way or another...besides, I have no idea what the OP might want from it...guesses, all guesses...crystal ball must be out of tune today...